# How to find the mean of all z scores above a cutoff

Tags: distributions, truncated-normal-distribution

I would like to find the mean of all z-scores above a z-score cutoff.  For example, what is the mean of all z scores above a z of 1.96 in a distribution N(0,1).

(My calculus skills are modest.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the *truncated normal distribution*. [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) gives explicit formulas for the mean.

In your example,

$$ \alpha=1.96,\quad \beta =\infty.$$

So, as per the Wikipedia page,

$$ \phi(\beta)=0, \quad \Phi(\beta)=1,\quad Z=\Phi(\beta)-\Phi(\alpha)=1-\Phi(\alpha) $$

and since $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, the mean you are looking for is

$$ \mu + \frac{\phi(\alpha)-\phi(\beta)}{Z}\sigma
= \frac{\phi(\alpha)}{1-\Phi(\alpha)}.$$

A quick rejection sample seems to confirm this:

```
alpha <- 1.96
nn <- 1e6
set.seed(1)
foo <- rnorm(nn)
mean(foo[foo>alpha])
# [1] 2.333103
dnorm(alpha)/(1-pnorm(alpha))
# [1] 2.337835
```

Answer (score 5):

By way of a supplement to Stephan's answer, note that the integration is quite straightforward. Let $\phi$ and $\Phi$ be the density and cdf of the standard normal.

We need simply notice that the exponent in a standard normal density is $-z^2/2$, which has a derivative of $-z$, and so by the chain rule for differentiation, $\phi'(z) = -z\,\phi(z)$ (with a little experience with integration this stuff becomes fairly easy to spot). Then:

$E(Z|Z>z)=1/(1-\Phi(z))\int_z^\infty u\,\phi(u)\, du =  (1-\Phi(z))\, [-\phi(u)]_z^\infty=\frac{\phi(z)}{1-\Phi(z)}$